# setting a position and size for buttons in java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm making project (periodic table) and have a little problem with Swing and GridBagLayout, i.e. when I want to get little bigger buttons, nothing changes or I get buttons that takes all of my screen. Why? How can I get it slightly bigger? And how can I set the buttons to NOT be in center?
My code (I'm using Swing and GridBagLayout):

```
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    JButton H,He,Li,Be,B,C,N,O,F,Ne;
    public MyPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        //Wodór
        H=new JButton("H");
        c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        c.weightx=1;
        c.weighty=1;
        c.gridwidth=2;
        c.gridheight=2;
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=0;
        add(H,c);
        //Hel
        He=new JButton("He");
        c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
        c.gridx=34;
        add(He,c);
        //Lit
        Li=new JButton("Li");
        c.weighty=0;
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=2;
        add(Li,c);
        //Beryl
        Be=new JButton("Be");
        c.gridx=2;
        add(Be,c);
        //Bar
        B=new JButton("B");
        c.gridx=24;
        add(B,c);
        //Węgiel
        C=new JButton("C");
        c.gridx=26;
        add(C,c);
        //Azot
        N=new JButton("N");
        c.gridx=28;
        add(N,c);
        //Tlen
        O=new JButton("O");
        c.gridx=30;
        add(O,c);
        //Fluor
        F=new JButton("F");
        c.gridx=32;
        add(F,c);
        //Neon
        Ne=new JButton("Ne");
        c.gridx=34;
        add(Ne,c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Best ways to change the size of a Swing button: Increase the size of the font or icon, or call [`setMargin(Insets)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin(java.awt.Insets)). **General tips:** 1) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) ..

Comment: .. and use it consistently. I'm guessing this is a periodic table? Same deal. 3) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of `weightx` and `weighty` in `GridBagConstraints`. In any case [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) will display the components in their preferred size, unless you set [fill](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#fill) to BOTH. Maybe [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) is more appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a picture of the Periodic Table that I got from DuckDuckGo.

[image: Perodic Table]

Looking at the table, I'd suggest two `GridLayouts`, one for the elements and one for the two series at the bottom.  You'd have to use dummy `JPanels` to fill out the empty portion of the elements `GridLayout`.

I'd also suggest that instead of `JButtons`, you create a model `JPanel` to hold the element abbreviation, element name, atomic number, and atomic weight.  You'd create an instance of the model `JPanel` for each element.

By using the model `JPanels`, you can more easily color the background.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a question about these parts where I got the help of others to layout a Periodic Table of the Elements. But .. damned if I can find it by searching! AFAIR we ended up using a `GridBagLayout` - as the OP is attempting.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: I'm sure you or I could create the Periodic Table with a *GridBagLayout*.  To me, it looks easier with a couple of *GridLaayouts*.  Neither you nor I  know what the OP is required to produce. since his question lacks details.